# activity_main.xml Doesn't Show Up

Tags: android-studio

I'm brand new in Android Studio and I am taking a course which has recorded 2 years ago. In that version of Android Studio, there is a xml file which named 'activity_main.xml' and the man who giving the course making edit on it. Now I am using latest version of Android Studio and there is no such a file! How can I reach that file?

I tried to find that file but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project, there are templates you can choose from. Try the `Empty Views Activity`, there should be some sample layout files there.

[image: New project dialog]

Comment: Appreciated that!